# Spring Transaction - How to allow dependent transactions to be complted if anyone fails

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I am using `"Spring TX"` `v 4.3.2.RELEASE` and also newbie to this. In my application, there are some dependent tasks, like in single transaction, I would like to insert data into `customer` and `address` irrespective of there is an exception.

Data should be get saved. Here I don't need to care about `Consistency` of data. I simply used `@Transactional` annotation on my service class, but in this case I expect `Customer` data should be saved if there is an issue while saving data of `address`. I tried below options but doesn't get worked.
`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. Please guide how we can do that ?

Code below for reference:
**CustomerService.java**

```
public interface CustomerService {
    public void createCustomer(Customer cust);
}
```

**CustomerServiceImpl.java**

```
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    public void setCustomerDAO(CustomerDAO customerDAO) {
        this.customerDAO = customerDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createCustomer(Customer cust) {
        customerDAO.create(cust);
    }
}
```

**CustomerDAO.java**

```
public interface CustomerDAO {
    public void create(Customer customer);
}
```

**CustomerDAOImpl.java**

```
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void create(Customer customer) {
        String queryCustomer = "insert into Customer (id, name) values (?,?)";
        String queryAddress = "insert into Address (id, address,country) values (?,?,?)";

        jdbcTemplate.update(queryCustomer, new Object[] { customer.getId(), customer.getName() });
        System.out.println("Inserted into Customer Table Successfully");

        jdbcTemplate.update(queryAddress, new Object[] { customer.getId(), customer.getAddress().getAddress(),customer.getAddress().getCountry() });
        System.out.println("Inserted into Address Table Successfully");
    }
}
```

**spring-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type DataSourceTransactionManager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


    <!-- MySQL DB DataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.driver.class.name}" />
        <property name="url" value="${mysql.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="customerDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.CustomerDAOImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerManager" class="com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.service.CustomerServiceImpl">
        <property name="customerDAO" ref="customerDAO"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**db.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `Address` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**TransactionManagerMain.java**

```
public class TransactionManagerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");

        CustomerService customerManager = ctx.getBean("customerManager", CustomerServiceImpl.class);

        Customer cust = createDummyCustomer();
        customerManager.createCustomer(cust);

        ctx.close();
    }

    private static Customer createDummyCustomer() {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(2);
        customer.setName("Pankaj");

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setId(2);
        address.setCountry("India");

        // setting value more than 20 chars, so that SQLException occurs
        address.setAddress("Albany Dr, San Jose, CA 95129");
        customer.setAddress(address);

        return customer;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other info.

```
Although I get below error, I expect 1st transaction should get committed.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into Address (id, address,country) values (?,?,?)]; Data truncation: Data too long for column 'address' at row 1; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'address' at row 1
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:941)
    at com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.dao.CustomerDAOImpl.create(CustomerDAOImpl.java:25)
    at com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.service.CustomerServiceImpl.createCustomer(CustomerServiceImpl.java:20)
    at com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.service.CustomerServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$faf0749.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.service.CustomerServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9dab5ce1.createCustomer(<generated>)
    at com.journaldev.spring.jdbc.main.TransactionManagerMain.main(TransactionManagerMain.java:18)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'address' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1623)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1715)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1455)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1440)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:877)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your error has nothing to do with transaction handling. Read its message:

```
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'address'
```

So, `"Albany Dr, San Jose, CA 95129"` is too long to fit in the address column.

Regarding your question, you're using a single transaction to save the customer and the address, so if an exception is thrown, everything will be rollbacked: that's the definition of a transaction. If you want the customer to be committed even if the address insertion fails, you need two transactions: one that saves the customer and commits, and a second one that saves the address and commits.

Comment: Hi JB - If I used `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)`, it allows me to save Customer data into table although there is an issue while saving data into address. This is what I want, with above annotation,  data is saving into customer table. Not Sure what Propagation.SUPPORTS does ?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#SUPPORTS. That probably works accidentally because in the absence of transaction, the connection auto-commits. As I said, you should have two transactions instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep them independent of each other, you need to keep them in different transactions. You will need to do something like this with Dao class:

```
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
        String queryCustomer = "insert into Customer (id, name) values (?,?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(queryCustomer, new Object[] { customer.getId(), customer.getName() });
        System.out.println("Inserted into Customer Table Successfully");
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createAddress(Customer customer) {
        String queryAddress = "insert into Address (id, address,country) values (?,?,?)"; 
        jdbcTemplate.update(queryAddress, new Object[] { customer.getId(), customer.getAddress().getAddress(),customer.getAddress().getCountry() });
        System.out.println("Inserted into Address Table Successfully");
    }
}
```

And remove the transactional annotation from service class. With this you will have two transactions starting at Dao layer for Customer and Address each and any error with one would not rollback the other one.